# How to not hardcode the values in the model in R

Tags: r, svm

In R SVM model, how can i change the to be predicted variable not being hardcoded in the model itself, rather be a variable name which can have different value.

```
svmmodel <- svm(SR~., data = dataSet)
```

Here how can i change SR~. to some variable which can have SR or someother value that needs to predicted

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: What is the issue precisely? can you not rename the columns of `dataSet` before calling `svm`?

Comment: Instead of using the `formula` to model your problem, you can use `x` an `y` as, respectively as independent variable and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build formuals dynamically in different ways. One way is to use `bquote()` to insert a symbol into the formula. For example

```
resp<-quote(SR)
bquote(.(resp)~.)
# SR ~ .
```

Or you can build your formula as a string

```
resp<-"SR"
dep<-"."
as.formula(paste(resp,dep,sep="~"))
# SR ~ .
```